# Crop part of map using Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I set bounds for Google Maps widget? For example, I need only [SW corner: 40.5, -25.5] - [NE corner 79.5, 178.5] rectangle. Now I'm using such code from another question:

```
var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.5, -25.5), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(79.5, 178.5)
);

// Listen for the dragend event
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

    // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

    var c = map.getCenter(),
        x = c.lng(),
        y = c.lat(),
        maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
        maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
        minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
        minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        if (x < minX) x = minX;
        if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
        if (y < minY) y = minY;
        if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
  });
```

But it doesn't give needed effect - anyway, this code allows to zoom map and user sees fragments across the strict bounds.

So, I would like to know, is there any method in API v3 to crop nesseasary part from full world map?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits is about requests limits per day

Comment: try https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!search/static$20maps$20google$20v3 the linmits page has the comment about the zoom

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=65.738268&lng=244.306000&zoom=3&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/so_wholeworldkmld.kml) (cover the map tiles outside your desired bounds with an opaque layer).

Comment: geocodezip, thanks for example, it's very close to what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I decided to solve this problem as [**geocodezip**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) advised.
For details see source code of
[**this page**](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=65.738268&lng=244.306000&zoom=3&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/so_wholeworldkmld.kml).

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you can just additionally disallow user to zoom out of your bounds by setting corresponding minZoom property

You can do it when initializing map, or after its already initialized like this:

```
 map.setOptions({minZoom:5});
```